# Generic class to hold JSON data of gerrit

Tags: c#, json, gerrit

The problem is that the gerrit response for getting all groups looks like this, and I find that having the name of the group outside of the {} creates problems for me because when I create a class to hold the group, I am forced to have the class named like the group to be able to deserialize the response.

But whenever a new gerrit group is created I don't want to create a new class with that name.

```
[{
"Administrators": {
  "id": "6a1e70e1a88782771a91808c8af9bbb7a9871389",
  "url": "#/admin/groups/uuid-6a1e70e1a88782771a91808c8af9bbb7a9871389",
  "options": {
  },
  "description": "Gerrit Site Administrators",
  "group_id": 1,
  "owner": "Administrators",
  "owner_id": "6a1e70e1a88782771a91808c8af9bbb7a9871389"
},
"Anonymous Users": {
  "id": "global%3AAnonymous-Users",
  "url": "#/admin/groups/uuid-global%3AAnonymous-Users",
  "options": {
  },
  "description": "Any user, signed-in or not",
  "group_id": 2,
  "owner": "Administrators",
  "owner_id": "6a1e70e1a88782771a91808c8af9bbb7a9871389"
},
"MyProject_Committers": {
  "id": "834ec36dd5e0ed21a2ff5d7e2255da082d63bbd7",
  "url": "#/admin/groups/uuid-834ec36dd5e0ed21a2ff5d7e2255da082d63bbd7",
  "options": {
    "visible_to_all": true,
  },
  "group_id": 6,
  "owner": "MyProject_Committers",
  "owner_id": "834ec36dd5e0ed21a2ff5d7e2255da082d63bbd7"
}]
```

Here are the classes:

```
public class Administrators
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public Options options { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int group_id { get; set; }
    public string owner { get; set; }
    public string owner_id { get; set; }
}

public class AnonymousUsers
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public  options { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int group_id { get; set; }
    public string owner { get; set; }
    public string owner_id { get; set; }
}

public class MyProjectCommitters
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public  options { get; set; }
    public int group_id { get; set; }
    public string owner { get; set; }
    public string owner_id { get; set; }
}
```

and what I want to do is have a class called GerritGroup to hold all this and to be able to deserialize any such group in an object.

The way I do it now is like this:

```
   IList<GerritGroup> grps  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<GerritGroup>>(cleanedResponse);
```

and I get a list with one object with all properties null.

Can you give me some advice regarding this JSON response?

Comment: might use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate json, for example   "visible_to_all": true *,*   - comma might be a reason of the parsing errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a collection that's holding an object with key-value pairs, where the keys are variable and the values are groups.

In other words, you only need one `Group` class:

```
public class Group
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> options { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int group_id { get; set; }
    public string owner { get; set; }
    public string owner_id { get; set; }
}
```

And you need to deserialize your JSON as a `List<Dictionary<string, Group>>`:

```
var groups = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, Group>>>(json);

foreach (var g in groups)
{
    foreach (var e in g)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Key + " " + e.Value.description);
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed this is what I did not understand. Thank you very much! It works like a charm!